# SQL query to obtain result from multiple unlinked tables in database

Tags: sql

There are two tables in a database as follows (Note that the 2 tables don't have any key in common.):-

> *Employee Table*
>
> **Eid**        **Ename**          **Salary**
>
> 001         John               15000
>
> 002        Mac                20000
>
> 003        Michael       6000
>
> 004       Randy           30000
>
> 005       Mandy         NULL
>
> *Salary Table*
>
> **MinSal**        **MaxSal**          **Grade**
>
> 1000               10000              A
>
> 11000          20000         B
>
> 21000          30000         C
>
> 31000          40000         D

Now the Output required is something like

> *Employee Details*
>
> **Eid**        **Ename**          **Salary**                 **Grade**
>
> 001          John               15000                   B
>
> 002          Mac                20000               B
>
> 003          Michael       6000               A
>
> 004         Randy          30000              C
>
> 005         Mandy          N/A               N/A

What is the logic or technique that is used to obtain the req. result. What can be the SQL Code for this.

Comment: `John` should get `B`, not `A`, right?

Answer (score 6):

You need a non-equi-join in your case:

```
select e.eid, e.ename, e.salary, s.grade
  from employee e inner join salary s on (e.salary between s.minsal and s.maxsal)
```

You might need to add a special case for your `N/A` case. Maybe a `left outer` join? It might help if you specify what's the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Right. And it should be a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to cover the last case (`Mandy`)

Comment: Thanks. The query you suggested works. But I still want to know the theory or logic (Verbal or Mathematical) and the way of thinking which can help one to arrive at the correct query?

Comment: @Rise: if you want to learn more about the theory behind relational databases and SQL, you need to learn about relational algebra. The query you were trying to resolve it's achieved with the `X` (cross-product) relational operator in combination with a `S` (selector) relational operator.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JOIN

Here's a useful page on how to use it: http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php

Answer (score 0):

I'd seriously suggest linking them, it would result in a better architecture and make coding easier.

However if you don't want to do that you can get the desired result using if statements, one for each of the pay grades.

Comment: I agree.  But to clarify This database is not under my control. I am only allowed to read data.